# Как скопировать сообщение Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот, aiogram

```py
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
async def video_file_id(message: types.Message):
    #получаю и отправляю message_id, у меня вышел 157
    await message.answer(message.message_id)
```

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="test1")
async def cmd_test1(message: types.Message):
    #пытаюсь вывести, но прога думает что это текст
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,157)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю это оно

```
# 1 вариант - копирует текущий обьект Message
# chat_id - идентификатор чата, в который нужно скопировать сообщение
await message.copy_to(chat_id=...)
# 2 вариант
# from_chat_id - идентификатор чата, где сообщение которое нужно скопировать
# message_id - идентификатор сообщения, которое нужно скопировать
await bot.copy_message(from_chat_id=..., chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=...)
```

Comment: Да, оно, жалко что для этого нет функции